# Format string/number "NNNNN"

Tags: c#, string, numbers, format

I have to write a progression of number, having (each) 5 digit. My code is:

```
int count = 1;
string labelCount = "";
foreach (var directory in folderList)
{
    if (count < 10)
    {
        labelCount = "0000" + count.ToString();
    }
    else if (count < 100)
    {
        labelCount = "000" + count.ToString();
    }
    else if (count < 1000)
    {
        labelCount = "00" + count.ToString();
    }
    else if (count < 10000)
    {
        labelCount = "0" + count.ToString();
    }

    count++;
}
```

but it doesnt looks so good in my opinion. Is there a way to format a number (adding 0xN to the left) or that's the only way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just give *format* to `ToString` method

```
var str = count.ToString("00000");
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.padleft.aspx):

```
string formatted = count.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
```

Comment: ... but be careful that `count` isn't negative. `000-42` is really ugly.

Comment: In his code count begins at `1` and is never decremented & you can deduce from the context that the variable will never be negative. Good general advice though, I agree.

Comment: Yes, this was meant as general advice. `count.ToString("00000")` works for all integers, but `PadLeft` as shown above works only for non-negative ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, It will help you...

```
labelCount  = string.Format("{0:00000}", count);
```

See here for all the Formats : [String.Format](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format)

Answer (score 0):

How about going like this ?

```
int count = 1;
string labelCount = "";

foreach (var directory in folderList)
{
   int i = 10000;
   while (count < i)
   {
       labelCount += 0;
       i /= 10;
   }

   labelCount += count.ToString();
   count++;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

```
string formatted = count.ToString();
for(int i = 0; i < count - 5; i++)
{
    formatted = "0" + formatted;
}
labelCount.Text = formatted;
```

EDIT: Sry, my fault! Should be:

```
//..
for(int i = 0; i < 5 - count.ToString().Length; i++)
//..
```

Comment: So if count is 10 then 5 zeros are added? If count is 100 95 zeros are added?